# An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Tags: networking, network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2, unc

I have a machine running multiple applications which constantly perform UNC access (`\\server-ip\share`). After several days all UNC become non-accessible from this machine.

- When killing the applications the UNC is accessible again
- When restarting the processes the UNC is immediately not accessible again
- Restarting the machine solves the problem for several days

Probably there is [Port exhaustion](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend/) but `netstat` does not reveal too many connections or hanging connections and the task manager performance tab does not show abnormal figures. TcpQry shows normal TCP/UDP mapping numbers.

Also

- Packet capture shows there is no request when problem happens (request not reaching network strengthening port exhaustion assumption).
- Event viewer does not reveal anything
- Did following registry changes although this would probably just delay problem not eliminate it but anyway it didn't help:

  Find the `autodisconnect` value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters`. If it's not there, create a new `REG_DWORD` called `autodisconnect`. Edit the value as Hexadecimal and set it to `ffffffff`.

  Find `KeepConn` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters`. If it doesn't exist create it as a `REG_DWORD` value and assign it the value 65534.

  Find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` and create a new `DWORD` value named `MaxUserPort`. Set the value to 65534.

My questions are:

- How to identify queue or buffer space exhaustion?
- If indeed UNC actions exhaust resources, is there an alternative that doesn't or is there a way to release the resources?

Comment: On which side did you view the number of connections? What information is your registry alteration based on?

Comment: The source machine. Target machine can still connect to source machine.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, are you discussing one or two machines? Please edit to be more clear, perhaps issuing the terms "server" and "client" if appropriate.